# Start Timer on Distance Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, countdown

In my game, there's an enemy. If this enemy is at a `minimalDistance` to the Player, a timer should start. This works fine, but I don't know how to show the Timer on the UI. I've tried this Script and attached a Text in the Inspector:

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EnemyFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text TimerText;
    public Transform target;
    public Transform myTransform;
    private const float minDistance = 5f;
    float TimeLeft = 10.0f;
    public float lockedY = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private string loadlevel;

    void Start()
    {
        TimerText.enabled = false;

        Vector3 tmp = transform.position;
        tmp.y = lockedY;
        transform.position = tmp;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Enemy follows the player
        transform.LookAt(target);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * 7 * Time.deltaTime);

        //If enemy is at minDistance, a Timer starts
        if ((myTransform.transform.position - target.transform.position).sqrMagnitude <= minDistance * minDistance)
        {
            TimeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
            TimerText.enabled = true;
            TimerText.text = "Drone sends Signal:" + Mathf.Round(Zeit);
        }

        //If the Countdown is done, the game is over
        if (Zeit < 0)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(loadlevel);
        }
    }
}
```

But the Text Shows up the whole game, still with "new text" displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably nothing else on the game object with the Text component, you might want to use `GameObject.SetActive(bool active)` instead but this probably won't fix your issue.

I can't help but think about a reference problem in the editor, missing a reference to your TimerText probably.

Comment: You're right! I put in the wrong Textobject (shame on me), but now there's another issue. If the enemy is killed, its script gets destroyed, but the Text still remains on the canvas. At that point, the text should be invisible. So how do I get access on the Textelement from another script?

Comment: Or you could also get an event when the enemy gets destroy from your EnemyFollow component using [`OnDestroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html) and disable/hide/delete the Text object/component.
You could also use [`OnDisable`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDisable.html) if you don't want to delete the elemy completly

Comment: Wow, didn't know about OnDisable. It totally worked! Thanks alot :)